# PowerShell Script to add date to folder name in list of home directories saved in variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am a PowerShell newbie.  I have a .csv file of users that I pulled a list of home directories for using the following:

```
$hdirpath = Get-Content C:\Temp\UserList.csv | ForEach {Get-ADUser $_ -properties HomeDirectory | Select HomeDirectory}
```

Output example of the above looks something like this:

### HomeDirectory

\servername\Users\roc03\username
\servername\Users\nov01\username
\servername\Users\roc05\username

Now I want to check if a folder exists in each users path and if it exists, i want to add today's date to the end of that folder name.  I know there's a If-Exist-Then command that I might be able to use but I'm not sure how to use it with the information saved in $hdirpath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Newbie myself so please forgive any mistakes.

From the top of my head I've got this in mind:

```
foreach ($path in $hdirpath) {

$folders = Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Select-Object FullName

$folders | if ($_.Name -eq "Folder Name") {Rename-Item "Folder Name" + Get-Date}
}
```

Someone will probably correct me, but if they don't give it a go and let me know if you have any problems.

Also - just for future reference, make sure you include code you have tried before posting a question.

**EDIT**

So, I've now got the following:

```
$hdirpath = Get-Content C:\temp\dir.txt

$fullDate = Get-Date
$date = $($fullDate.ToShortDateString())
$day = $date -replace "/", "."

foreach ($path in $hdirpath) {

    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} |
        Rename-Item -NewName {if ($_.Name.StartsWith('target') -and $_.Name.EndsWith('folder')) {$_.Name + " " + $($day)}}
}
```

This returns multiple errors saying that it `Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument input did not produce any output.`, but it works and appends the folder name with the current date.

Line 3-5 get the date and format it with "." rather than "\". You can format this however works for you obviously.

My test structure was "C:\temp\roc6\username1" - with multiple subfolders and multiple 'usernameX'. My test folder to re-name was called "targetfolder". End result ended with "targetfolder 08.03.2017".

**Revision**

This would be my final run of the script - with my limited knowledge this is the best I can do.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$hdirpath = Get-Content C:\temp\dir.txt

$fullDate = Get-Date
$day = $($fullDate.ToShortDateString()) -replace "/", "."

foreach ($path in $hdirpath) {
   Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} |
   Rename-Item -NewName {if ($_.Name.StartsWith('target') -and $_.Name.EndsWith('folder')) {$_.Name + " " + $($day)}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  My code was 'Get-Item -Path "\\servername\Users\roc06\username\Portability" | Rename-Item -NewName "Portability$(Get-Date -Format ""MMddyyyy"")" ' which works when dealing with one user at a time.  When I tried your code, I unfortunately got an error stating the term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...etc.  I tried adding 'foreach-object' before 'If' and got an error stating A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: I remember sorting the date out into the format I wanted and stuck it in a variable at the top of my script. Maybe if you had list of user names you could swap the "username" out of "\\servername\users\roc06\username\portability" bit with a variable? Then use the foreach function on that? (Sorry posting from my phone or would post example code)

Comment: Wish it were that easy. Unfortunately that won't work because the folder above username, in this case roc06, isn't always the same for each user.  This is why I have to use the fullpath for each user in the variable $hdirpath.

Comment: Ok I'll have to have another proper look tomorrow for you and try replicate it on my end

Comment: @user3642200 - I've added a new script at the bottom of my answer. Give it a go and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: FYI - I'll add an amended version of the code that deals with the errors.

Comment: What are you using in place of 'target' in ($_.Name.StartsWith('target')?

Comment: the "target" bit is the start of my test folder name. So, test folder name = "targetfolder" - so the `$_.name.startswith` and `$_.name.endswith` both aim at the start of the folder name and the end of the folder name.
So in your case, you'd swap this out with the folder you want to append with the date.
Eg: your folder is called "My Folder of Photos" - you could have `$_.name.StartsWith('My')` and `$_.name.EndsWith('Photos')` - hope that makes sense

Comment: It's working but it's adding today's date 3 times at the end of the folder.  I am getting the Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' error as you expected.  I took out the Endswith part of the Rename-Item section so doing that may be causing this.

Comment: I only added in the `EndsWith` bit as I was testing with mutliple folder names and it caught a folder that could have started with the same but was in fact a different folder. My test example was "targetfolderother" was still caught in the script to append the date but was not the actual "targetfolder" we were after. Let me know if adding it back in fixes the issue?

Comment: Yes.  It's working with Endswith added back in and using the same folder name for Startswith and Endswith.  Thanks for this!